# Make Lightbox Link External Webpage

Tags: hyperlink, lightbox

If I have a lightbox gallery, is it possible to link one of the images to an external website? So that the other images are treated as the regular lightbox, but if you click on one of the images you are sent to an external webpage?

This solution doesn't work:

```
<div id="gallery" style="display:inline;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.linktohere.com" >
                <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image2.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar. $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image2.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image3.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar. $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image3.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Are there any ways to work around this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<htm>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#gallery a').next().lightBox();
        });
    </script>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gallery" style="display:inline;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.linktohere.com" >
                <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image2.jpg" title="title one">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image2.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image3.jpg" title="title two">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image3.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use the function .next() to take the next element, all others will be selected exempt the first one.

the use of query like this is more common and it'll be usually be more readable.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Something like this can also be used if you modify the example a bit. so if the attribute selector finds "title" then use lightbox. If you do it like this then it doesn't mather anymore if your actual link is the first element or not.

Comment: Thanks. I simplified the example a little bit. What I really need is to have 10 various links out of 40 link externally, while the others link to the lightbox. So I guess I need to modify the attribute selector as you mentioned, but having a little difficulty applying that model to my example. Perhaps I should add an id to the <li> elements in question and link those to the lightbox? If so, I'm guessing my lightbox javascript would look something like: $(function(){$('#gallery.li a').lightBox();}); Or am I completely off base here? Thanks for the advice.